# How do we represent each of these statements as the symbol.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The only problem I am not sure about is 3d but to be for sure are the rest also correct?

> 3. (4 points) In this problem the following notation is used for the set of integers and three of its subsets:
>      The set of integers: $\mathbb Z$
>      The set of silly integers: $S$
>      The set of proud integers: $P$
>      The set of wild integers: $W$
>      (It is not necessary to know what is meant by a silly, proud or wild integer to do this problem.)
>      Using only the symbols $8,\mathbb Z, S, P, W, \emptyset, \subseteq, \in, \cup,\cap, -, =, \{, \}, ), (,$ and $\neq$, express the following statements.
>      (a) $8$ is a silly or wild integer.
>      (b) All wild integers are silly.
>      (c) Every proud integer is wild but not silly.
>      (d) There are integers that are not silly and not wild.
>      [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/572EE.png)

[My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPuth.jpg):

3a. $\{8\in S\cup 8\in W\}$
3b. $W\subseteq S$
3c. $P\subseteq (W-S)$

Comment: Please type out the problems and your work. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: B) and c) are correct but a) is not.  you have the "in" inside st brackets where it doesn't make sense. For d it would be nice if you could use the complement symbol but you can make do with setminus.  How would you indicate that there are numbers that are both?  So how do you indicate that there are numbers that are neither?  How would you indicate there *aren't* numbers that are neither? (Or not both?)

Comment: Your answer to 3a) reads as "a set with the element: the union of '8 is a silly integer' with '8 is a wild integer'" which isn't a statement at all, it's merely a description of a set with an impossible element that makes no sense.  The impossible element is a set union of two things that are statements and not sets.

Comment: As @fleablood points out, your answer to 3a. is nonsense. I would write it simply as $8 \in S \cup W$.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of hoping the op would figure it on their own.  {8 in S} is set whose single element is a statement.  "Happy Birthday" $\cup $ 8 $\in S $ is the union of two statements.  That's.... gibberish as statements aren't sets.  It's a bit like saying "Burp tadpole nosering the".  But $8 \in S \cup W $ is the perfectly sensible statement "8 is in the set that is the union of wild integers combined with silly integers".

Comment: 3a. oh okay, thank you i realized why this was wrong

Answer (score 0):

(d) $\emptyset \ne (\mathbb Z\setminus (S\cup W))$

Explanation: Empty set is not equal with set of all integers without the union of silly integers and wild integers. In other words, there are some integers that are neither silly nor wild.